# Show the number(count) of each list item by the total number of items

Tags: html, jquery

I want to show the number of each list item in a group by the to total
number of items in that group.

For e.g: 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4 respectively

I have followed a couple answers to almost similar questions on the forum and gotten to the point
where the total displays but i can't get the individual number
or each list in the group to display alongside the total.

My HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 1</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 2</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 2</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 2</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var ImgIndex = $(".list-group li").index() + 1;
    var ImgTotal = $( ".list-group li" ).length;

      $(".list-group li").each(function(){
        ImgIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
      });

      $('.li-count').html(''+ImgIndex+'/'+ImgTotal+'');
});
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ImgTotal = $( ".list-group li" ).length;

$(".list-group li").each(function(index,value){
      $(this).find('.li-count').html(''+(index+1)+'/'+ImgTotal+'');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text(function)`. The first argument of the function is the index within the collection

```js
var ImgTotal = $( ".list-group li" ).length;

$('.li-count').text(i => (i+1) + '/' + ImgTotal)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 1</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 2</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 2</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><p class="li-count"></p><h3>Title 2</h3></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```